# What is the fastest int to float conversion on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, casting, floating-point, integer

I am converting some Int16s and Int32s to float and then back again.

I'm just using a straight cast, but doing this 44100 times per second (any guesses what its for? :) )

Is a cast efficient? Can it be done any faster?

P.S Compile for thumb is turned off.

Comment: Why do you need to do the conversions?  You might get a better answer if you explain more about your end goal.  For example, in many situations, you can just leave them as floats the whole time.

Comment: im doing effects processing that must be done on a float and i have signed integer samples.

Comment: How accurate do your conversions/calculations have to be? There are quite a few "non IEEE compliant" floating point libraries that often perform better.

Comment: Remove [Unanswered] from thread title and you'll gain back my upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two ways to know.

1) Read the code the compiler generates for promoting ints to floats in your case.

2) Measure the performance of the code the compiler generates vs. other options.

To do the former, set the SDK to Device and the Active Architecture to arm, and choose Build > Show Assembly Code.  Then read the compiler-generated code.

If you are smarter than a compiler then you can write your own assembly code and use it instead.  Odds are you aren't.

If you are doing an operation many, many times, Instruments will do a good job at showing you how many processor samples it's taking.  But Jim's point is valid, and you shouldn't dismiss it as unhelpful: in an operation involving math on floating-point numbers, compiler type promotion is the *least* of your worries.  Chips are built to do that in two or three cycles, and compilers usually manage to make that happen.  But the effects processing you're doing will probably take **thousands** of cycles.  The promotion will be lost in the noise.

Answer (score 1):

Is a cast efficient?  In your case, I'd guess it's efficient enough.

Can it be done faster? Maybe...but would it be worth the effort?  Have you benchmarked it and discovered a performance problem due to the cast operations?

If you're doing anything mathematically nontrivial with the floating point sample data,
I'd be really surprised if the casts turned out to be a significant bottleneck!

Comment: its not so much it is a bottleneck, im just up against the wall in terms of performance and looking for every increase of speed i can get, so id still like to know how to do it faster

Comment: i have marked this answer as unhelpful as it doesnt answer the question. the forums here promote discussion, this answer does not. whether or not my program needs it this is a question that if answered correctly will be utilized by the iphone community, and an answer like this helps a question like this go unanswered.

Comment: after reflection, your answer was good enough, edit your answer and ill upvote it.